# Reset existing HBITMAP as desktop background (Win32)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, hbitmap, gdi

I wish to create a transparent window over the desktop.
For that purpose I've created an HDC with a background of the desktop (created HBITMAP of the desktop and applied it to my HDC), and invoked *UpdateLayeredWindow*.

So far, so good.
for performance issues i need to keep a persistent GDI+ object, meaning my HDC and HBITMAP need to stay the same handles between paintings (assuming the desktop DC didn't change), same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074294/win32-does-a-window-have-the-same-hdc-for-its-entire-lifetime).

In the first painting iteration all goes well. in the second painting iteration, since the HDC and HBITMAP haven't changed, I repaint on the existing HDC, meaning i get double images (the background is not erased).

Here's a code example of what I'm doing:

```
bool SomeUI::Draw()
{
    BLENDFUNCTION blend = {0};
    POINT ptPos = {0};
    SIZE sizeWnd = {0};
    POINT ptSrc = {0};
    BOOL bUpdate = FALSE;

    // Get the client rect
    RECT rctWindow;
    bool bGot = GetWindowRect(rctWindow);
    if (!bGot)
        return false;

    // Get the desktop's device context
    HDC hDCDesktop = GetDC(NULL);
    if (!hDCDesktop)
        return false;

    int nWidth = abs(rctWindow.right - rctWindow.left);
    int nHeight = abs(rctWindow.bottom - rctWindow.top);

    // Create 32Bit bitmap to apply PNG transparency
    VOID *ppvBits = NULL;
    BITMAPINFO BitmapInfo = {0};
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = nWidth;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = nHeight;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateDIBSection(hDCDesktop, &BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &ppvBits, NULL, 0);
    if (!hBmp || hBmp==(HBITMAP)ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
        goto releaseHandles;

    // Create a compatible DC and select the newly created bitmap
    if (!m_hDC)
    {
        m_hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDCDesktop);
        if (!m_hDC)
            goto releaseHandles;

        SelectObject(m_hDC, hBmp);
    }
    else
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        // The problem lies here, this is where I need to reset the HBITMAP 
        // according to the desktop here (to have a transparent DC to work on)
        //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    // The drawing logic
    bool bInnerDraw = Draw(m_hDC);
    if (!bInnerDraw)
        goto releaseHandles;

    // Call UpdateLayeredWindow
    blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
    sizeWnd.cx = nWidth;
    sizeWnd.cy = nHeight;
    ptPos.x = rctWindow.left;
    ptPos.y = rctWindow.top;
    bUpdate = UpdateLayeredWindow(m_hWnd, hDCDesktop, &ptPos, &sizeWnd, m_hDC, &ptSrc, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);
    if (!bUpdate)
        goto releaseHandles;

releaseHandles:
    // releasing handles
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Answer:

In order to reset the persistent HBITMAP, (reminder: it needs to stay the same handle), we'll set the desktop background of that area to a temporary HBITMAP and copy it to the persistent HBITMAP.
To achieve that (copying from one HBITMAP to the other), We'll create a temporary HDC and select the temporary HBITMAP to it, and copy the temporary HDC to the persistent HDC, usint *BitBlt*

Here's the code:

```
        hBmpTemp = CreateDIBSection(hDCDesktop, &BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &ppvBits, NULL, 0);
        if (!hBmpTemp || hBmpTemp==(HBITMAP)ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
            goto releaseHandles;

        HDC hTempDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
        if (!hTempDC)
            goto releaseHandles;

        SelectObject(hTempDC, hBmpTemp);

        ::BitBlt(m_hPersistentDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hTempDC, rctWindow.left, rctWindow.top, SRCCOPY);

        ::DeleteDC(hTempDC);
```